# What is the difference between "queries" and "commands" in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, geolocation

Hello MongoDB documentation specifies that there are several ways to retrieve documents near a geographical position :

- using "queries" (in find queries for instance) :
  https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/operator/query-geospatial/
- or using "commands" :
  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/nav-geospatial/

I don't understand the difference between commands and operator/queries ? These commands seem to do exactly the same thing as their query counterparts ?

PS : I use scala reactivemongo connector in my application.

Answer (score 2):

I remembered reading it from [mongodb definitive guide 2nd edition (mongo 2.6)](https://books.google.co.id/books?id=uGUKiNkKRJ0C&pg=PA76&lpg=PA76&dq=database%20command%20always%20returns%20a%20document%20containing&source=bl&ots=h8pwMcbTwj&sig=YNofSiX2He0FFzSSTYCx4xAE-9A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi8_d_HloLPAhVMp48KHU8lB5QQ6AEIJzAC#v=onepage&q=database%20command%20always%20returns%20a%20document%20containing&f=false), however this book only covers mongo2.6.

1. query command cover several tasks like CRUD, drop database. While database Command cover everything else, including administrative tasks, cloning database, etc. *(this book uses mongodb v2.6, I am sure in mongodbV3.2 queryCommand has more functions that can cover some adminitrative tasks)*
2. query in mongoshell returned a cursor, while database command returned an document that always has "ok" status, and one or more information.

---

example querying geolocation with database Command

```
db.runCommand( {
       geoNear: <collection> ,
       near: { type: "Point" , coordinates: [ <coordinates> ] } ,
       spherical: true,
       ...
    } )
```

example of querying database with query command

```
db.places.find(
   {
     location:
       { $near :
          {
            $geometry: { type: "Point",  coordinates: [ -73.9667, 40.78 ] },
            $minDistance: 1000,
            $maxDistance: 5000
          }
       }
   }
)
```

Comment: Thank you vdj4y so it is just a syntaxe différence ? Why bother having two different syntaxes on a restricted set of queries in MongoDb ?Is there a performance différence ? Is it only new features beeing first introduced as commands prior to being integrated in the query language ?